# My JQuery is not working on Chrome, sometimes works on firefox and then stops

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, google-chrome

when I click on the menu Icon, sometimes it works but after refreshing 3 or 4 times it stops. not working in Chrome at all. am i missing something. Please help.

```
$(function () {
  const menu = $(".fa-3x");
  const list = $(".show");
  const main = $("#firstpage");
  const last = $("#secondpage");

  menu.on("click", _=> {
    $(".show").toggleClass("hide");
  });
});
```

[Mock-up Site here - codepen](https://codepen.io/briansaved/pen/YYoOoW)

Comment: I don't know how codepen works exactly, but you don't need html, head and body tags. I removed them and add jquery by clicking on the cog above the javascript window, and selecting jquery. Do the same for all you external css or script. And it will works

Comment: Please check my fork : https://codepen.io/Alvan/pen/dJxvpL?editors=1111

Comment: I have just checked again now and not working. have you tried to refresh a couple of times. it ends up stopping and i cant figure out why.

Comment: On my forks its works forever, and i work with google chrome

Comment: I want to start with the menu closed. so on your fork, i swapped the classes and started the html with class hide then toggleclass show and when that happens, it stops. could you try it please.

Comment: Add the "hide" class to the menu button, but do not remove the show one. Else you your jquery selector won't work. I recommend you to set class="menu hide", see my codepen: https://codepen.io/Alvan/pen/dJxvpL?editors=1111

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The query selector is wrong. `$(".show").toggleClass("hide");`

It could be better to use `#menulinks` to access related `lu` element.

```
$("#menulinks").on("click", _=> {
   $("#menulinks ul").toggleClass("hide");
});
```

**Demo**

```js
/* jshint esversion:6 */
/* global $ */


$(function () {

    $("#menulinks").on("click", _=> {
       $("#menulinks ul").toggleClass("hide");
    });


});
```

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    /* makes the image fill entire screen*/
}


.name,
.scroller {
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    text-align: center;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    /* makes text in perfect mid*/
}

h1 {
    font-family: "Inconsolata", monospace;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

.name {
    top: 45%;
}

.show {
    width: 130px;
    background: rgba(3, 4, 32, 0.54);
    position: relative;
    left: 43px;
    visibility: visible;
    opacity: 1;
    z-index: 4;
    transition: 0.3s;
}

.fa-3x:hover,
#arrow:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
    opacity: 0.75;

}

.hidden li:hover a,
.name,
a:hover {
    background: linear-gradient(to right, #215AF6, #F2359D);
    -webkit-background-clip: text;
    -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.info {
    font-size: 350%;
    padding: 0;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    letter-spacing: 5px;
}

.description {
    letter-spacing: 4px;
    word-spacing: 5px;
}

header {
    background: linear-gradient(rgba(17, 20, 42, 0.95), rgba(17, 20, 42, 0.95)), url("https://images.pexels.com/photos/399636/pexels-photo-399636.jpeg?w=940&h=650&auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb") center;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-size: cover;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    height: 100vh;
    color: white;
}

#secondpage {
    background-size: cover;
    height: 100vh;

}

div.scroller {
    position: absolute;
    top: 95%;
    left: 50%;

}

.scrolltext {
    font-size: 10px;
    letter-spacing: 3px;
    padding-top: 0;
}

.material-icons.md-100 {
    font-size: 100px;
    margin-top: -20px;
}

#menulinks {
    text-align: left;
    padding: 20px;
}

nav p {
    font-size: 65%;
    letter-spacing: 4px;
}

li a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
    padding-left: 10px;
    font-size: 90%;

}

ul {
    list-style: none;

}

li {
    padding: 5px;

}

.hide {
    opacity: 0;
    visibility: hidden;
}

.show li:hover {
    background: rgba(3, 4, 32, 1);
    padding-left: 12px;
    transition: 0.3s;

}

.dp {
    max-width: 400px;
    max-height: 200px;
    filter: grayscale(100%);
}


#bottom {
    max-height: 110px;
    max-width: 350px;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin: 0 auto;
    margin-top: 230px;
    margin-bottom: 50px;
    text-align: center;

}

#summary,
#greeting {
    max-width: 400px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 20px;
}

#greeting {
    letter-spacing: 10px;
    word-spacing: 10px;

}

#summarytext,
#span {
    line-height: 150%;
    font-size: 20px;
}

#span {
    margin-top: 30px;
}

.fa-2x {
    opacity: 0.1;
}
```

```html
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <title>Brian Profile</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
    <script defer src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.4/js/all.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <header id="firstpage">
        <nav id="menulinks">
            <i class="fas fa-align-justify fa-3x"></i>
            <p>menu</p>
            <ul class="hide">
                <li id="firstopt"><a href="#">About</a></li>
                <li id="secondopt"><a href="#">Experience</a></li>
                <li id="thirdopt"><a href="#">Portfolio</a></li>
                <li id="fourthopt"><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
        <div class="name">
            <h1 class="info">Hello, I'm Brian</h1>
            <p class="description">an aspiring web developer</p>
        </div>
        <div class="scroller">
            <p class="scrolltext"> SCROLL DOWN</p>
            <i class="material-icons md-100" id="arrow">expand_more</i>
        </div>
    </header>
    <footer id="secondpage">
        <div id="bottom">
            <p>
                <img src="https://dl.dropbox.com/s/3c0xlv56hhb1ed7/2013-07-20%2021.58.43.jpg?=raw1" alt="InstaPic" class="dp"></p>
        </div>
        <div id="greeting">
            <span>HI THERE</span>
            <p><i class="far fa-window-minimize fa-2x"></i></p>
        </div>
        <div id="summary">
            <p id="summarytext">
                I am a web developer based in <a href="#">London</a>. With a growing Portfolio that is constantly updated, I have a passion for all things 'web'.</p>
            <p id="span"><span>For more information visit my <a href="#" class="blog">Blog</a>.</span>
            </p>



        </div>

    </footer>


    <script src="scripts.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Wow, thanks. This has solved it. What is confusing me though is it was working in firefox for sometime before breaking. Why?

Comment: "$(".show").toggleClass("hide");" this approach exactly dangerous. You would change all elements which have "show" classes to hide.